# zoom level listener in google maps v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-mobile, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an Android app that is supposed to use Google Maps v2.
Now i'm stuck at finding when zoom level of map has changed.
Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Create an implementation [of `OnCameraChangeListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener), and pass an instance of it [to `setOnCameraChangeListener()` of your `GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnCameraChangeListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener%29). Your listener should be called with `onCameraChange()` whenever the user changes the zoom, center, or tilt. You find out the new zoom level from the `CameraPosition` object that you are passed.

Comment: setOnCameraChangeListener is now deprecated

Comment: @CommonsWare what if I want to detect only zoom onDoubleTap on google map??

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat: I have  no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 54):

If you're looking for how to determine if the zoom level has changed from the previous zoom level, here's what I'd suggest:

Define an instance variable to keep track of the previous zoom level:

```
//Initialize to a non-valid zoom value
private float previousZoomLevel = -1.0f;
```

Also, define an instance variable to let you know if the map is zooming:

```
private boolean isZooming = false;
```

When you setup your GoogleMap instance, give it an OnCameraChangeListener...

```
//mMap is an instance of GoogleMap
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());
```

Now, define the OnCameraChangeListener that will determine if the zoom level has changed:

```
public OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new OnCameraChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) 
        {
            Log.d("Zoom", "Zoom: " + position.zoom);

            if(previousZoomLevel != position.zoom)
            {
                isZooming = true;
            }

            previousZoomLevel = position.zoom;
        }
    };
}
```

Now, you can check the value of isZooming to know if you are changing zoom levels.

Make sure to set

```
isZooming = false;
```

after you've completed whatever action relies on knowing if the map is zooming.

Comment: Also works perfectly as a drag listener. Exactly what I was looking for to filter markers view by the distance to the map center. Thanks!

Comment: deprecated now.

Comment: As is deprecated, use `onCameraMoveStarted` instead

Answer (score 42):

Since previous answers are based on `OnCameraChangeListener` and that is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener), this answer is based on camera [`OnCameraMoveListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener).

In this example, I am changing my [Map Type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_types) when user changes the zoom (using controls or fingers and zooming).

If [zoom level](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom) changes to **above** `18.0`, map type changes to `MAP_TYPE_HYBRIB` and
If [zoom level](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom) changes to **below** `18.0`, map type changes to `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL`.

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMove() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
        if(cameraPosition.zoom > 18.0) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        } else {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice!  Much cleaner than OnCameraChangeListener.  Interesting idea to change the map type.

Comment: note: this callback is triggered quite a few times for each zoom event

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Yes, it is. While user is zooming in, each "phase" of the zoom will have a trigger. The slower you zoom in/out, the more times it will trigger the listener. The faster you zoom in/out, the less times it will trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can also override `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener` and register it with a `GogleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener` method:

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener { reason ->
   when (reason) {
      GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE -> {
         //handle this state
      }
    }
}
```