# Handling lots of makers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm building an application that uses Google Maps Android API v2 and can display lots of markers in some locations. Do you know any good practice on handling many markers in an application that tracks user's location to bring new markers and allows him to also pan the map?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732286/1103584

or this [Hiding and Showing on screen Markers with Google Maps Android API V2](http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/hiding-and-showing-on-screen-markers-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/)