# Control zoom level when using Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps-utils

I am using Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility to enable clustering for my markers. In order to use this library, i need to set the map's **cameraChangeListener** to be object of type **ClusterManager**. 
The problem is that i want to control the minimum zoom level, so that when zoom level goes below some threshold, to set it's value back to so predefined value. But, when i set **onCameraChangeListener** to object of type **ClusterManager** i lose the possibility to control the zoom level.

Does somebody know how to control zoom level when using this library ?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/pull/1/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will test this later, but roughly, you'll need to customize your `onCameraChangeListener` a bit.

As specified in @DiscDev's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973886/zoom-level-listener-in-google-maps-v2-in-android), register a callback method on the map as follows:
`mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener())`.

Your getCameraChangeListener should handle the zoom the way you want it to, before calling ClusterManager:

```js
public OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
  return new OnCameraChangeListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position)
    {
        if (position.zoom < [minimum desired position]) {
          mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( [float value of desired zoom level] );
        }
        mClusterManager.onCameraChange(mMap.getCameraPosition());
    }
  }
}
```