# How to listen to Zoom level changes in Android google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would to listen to Zoom level changes.

I tried this solution but it is deprecated.

```kotlin
mMap?.setOnCameraChangeListener(object : OnCameraChangeListener {             
    private var currentZoom = -1f

    override fun onCameraChange(pos: CameraPosition) {
        if (pos.zoom != currentZoom) {
            currentZoom = pos.zoom
            // do you action here                         
            Toast.makeText(this@,"Zoom$currentZoom",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()                 
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this solution but it is deprecated. \n
```mMap?.setOnCameraChangeListener(object : OnCameraChangeListener {
            private var currentZoom = -1f
            override fun onCameraChange(pos: CameraPosition) {
                if (pos.zoom != currentZoom) {
                    currentZoom = pos.zoom
                    // do you action here
                    Toast.makeText(this@,"Zoom$currentZoom",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })```

Comment: This answer shows you what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40566288/2711811. You'll have to translate it from java to Kotlin.

Comment: You can check the different samples in Maps SDK for Android Official documentation for Camera change events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/events#camera_change_events